# How to install OpenDDS 3.12 on windows system

Tags: c++, perl, command-prompt, data-distribution-service, opendds

I recently try to install OpenDDS-3.12 on my windows7 OS.

But, it has make trouble.

When I try to type `configure` on VS command prompt, it can't detect Visual C++ version!

Error code is like this:

```
Colud not detect Visual C++ version, try running this script from
 the Visual Studio Command Prompt.
Stopped at configure line 410.
```

Somebody help me my problem.

(Active perl version is 5.24.1, VS version is 2017)

Comment: Did you install ActiveState Perl first? What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I had no trouble installing it in a developer command prompt using Visual Studio 2017 Community with Perl available.

Comment: Yes I already installed ActiveState Perl. And I also use Visual Studio 2017 Community

Comment: Make sure you actually installed C++ with Visual Studio. It is easy to not install it. If it is installed then cl /? in the developer prompt should give you some output.

Comment: When I type the message "cl /?" in VS prompt, prompt print "c/c++ compiler option". I think it is no problem about my VS prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue while I had my visual studio correctly installed. I figured out that the configure script of openDDS is checking the output of the cl.exe command and expect a compiler version displayed in English!. Mine was displayed in french, so it didn't work. I had to install the English package to get the visual studio command prompt in English. it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run configure from the Visual Studio command prompt. When it still gives the same error post the output of

> cl /?

Comment: When I type the message "cl /?" in VS prompt, prompt print "version 19.00.24215.1". I think it is no problem about my VS prompt.
But, I don't know why OpenDDS Colud not detect Visual C++ version.

Comment: It seems OpenDDS expects 19.1 as compiler output for Visual Studio 2017, have you installed all Visual Studio 2017 updates?

Answer (score 0):

VS2015 / VS2017 doesn't install c++ compiler by default.

- Modify VS VS2015 / VS2017 and select c++ compiler and install if VS VS2015 / VS2017 already install.
- configure

Note: OpenDDS-3.12 will not build on VS 2012