# How can I configure the OpenDDS 3.13 with VS2017 community?

Tags: perl, visual-studio-2017, opendds

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.  Below is the output from a Visual Studio Developer command prompt indicating the C++ version.

```
C:\ProgramsNotInstalled\OpenDDS-3.13>cl /?
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27024.1 for x86
```

Following that, I see the following output when running the configure --java command.

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.3
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************

C:\ProgramsNotInstalled\OpenDDS-3.13>configure
ERROR: Could not detect Visual C++ version, try running this script from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.
Stopped at configure line 421.

C:\ProgramsNotInstalled\OpenDDS-3.13>configure --java
ERROR: Could not detect Visual C++ version, try running this script from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.
Stopped at configure line 421.

C:\ProgramsNotInstalled\OpenDDS-3.13>
```

I saw a similar question posed for DDS 3.12 on stack overflow but that answer has to do with language.  That is clearly not the problem in my case, and I am running the configure script from the correct type of command prompt.  This question is not a duplicate.
[How to install OpenDDS 3.12 on windows system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035888/how-to-install-opendds-3-12-on-windows-system)

Comment: What output do you get from `configure --verbose`?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, the configure script cannot always detect the compiler version automatically.  I'm not good at reading perl scripts because I don't know perl well, but I found an option to help the script.

First determine the exact version of the C++ compiler by running this line:

```
cl /?
```

Now using the output of that, add the --compiler option to the command line.

```
configure --compiler=19.16.27024.1 --java
```

The instructions within the INSTALL file and README were not clear on that point.  I ran configure --help to look at the command line options and that is how I learned that the script will try to autodetect the compiler.  My guess is that the script is looking for a specific C++ compiler version or it is using a regex that isn't working well.

Comment: Wouldn't that set `$opts{compiler}`, not `$opts{compiler_version}`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a small issue in the configure script of OpenDDS 3.13 which is caused by a change in the compiler version which was not known at release time. When you would pull github master (see https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS) this should work again, or wait until OpenDDS 3.14.